# Error in installing openbabel (could not build wheels)

Tags: python, installation, openbabel

I typed

```
pip install openbabel
```

in the terminal, and it gave me this error:
`Failed to build openbabel ERROR: Could not build wheels for openbabel, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

What could be wrong here?

1. I tried updating pip and setuptools
2. I tried installing the wheel using

```
pip install openbabel-wheel
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the documentation, you would need to download the binary first

> First you need to download and install the main Open Babel executable and library as described in Install a binary package.

Documentation: https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UseTheLibrary/PythonInstall.html

Binary: https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation/install.html#install-binaries